# Definition of space $L_f^2$ where $f$ is a function?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, hilbert-spaces, definition, normed-spaces

http://it.tinypic.com/r/2iqjvbl/9

Hi guys! I'm writing my thesis for my degree and it's about Sturm-Liouville theory applications. I'm using the book "Al-Gwaiz M.A. Sturm-Liouville Theory and Its Applications" for references and here I have a problem. In the image you can see that I underlined in black the space $L_\rho^2$, where $\rho$ is a function, and its norm because the book does not define it and I don't know/understand its definition. Can someone please help me telling me the definition of this space or some references where I can find it?

Comment: they have there $p$ and $\rho$, $\rho$ isn't a function and so your f isn't function

Comment: No, ρ is a function and is defined as an integral of q and p Sturm-Liouville equation functions. Can you explain better what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a [weighted $L^p$-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Weighted_Lp_spaces).

The norm is given by
$$
\|u\|_{L^2_\rho} ^p:=\int_D |u(x)|^2 \rho(x) dx,
$$
scalar product is
$$
(u,v)_\rho = \int_D \rho(x) u(x)v(x)dx.
$$